# How to use Floats with Map<> getParams()

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm sending data to my ``.php` script file, which stores that data to my Database.

I'm using `Map<String, String>` with `getParams()` for that.

However, I'm quite new to Java and cant figure out how to return `Float` from Params.

What do i need to change here so I could return `Floats`?

I keep getting errors that `Map` has to be `<String, String>`.

I've tried correcting the Map and getParams with various statments, but that didn't work. Also I tried deleting the , that fixed any error but the app just crashes.

```
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        //Here is what I think i need to change
        Map <String, String>params = new HashMap();
        params.put("tire", tire);
        params.put("tire2", tire2);
        // tire and tire 2 are floats
        return params;
    }
```

I expect the return `params` to return the first option as a `String` and the second as a `Float`.

Comment: You're question is not clear: if you declare in the signature of the method that it returns a map from string to string, why inside the method are you trying to return a map from string to float? Second, the way you declare a new map should be: `new HashMap<>()` IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value type of your map is `String`, so you would need to convert/format your values to that. You could just use `Float.toString(float)`:

```
params.put("tire", FLoat.toString(tire));
```

Or maybe you want to format your numbers with a specific number of decimals (rounded to two points here):

```
params.put("tire", String.format("%.2f", tire));
```

Comment: The problem is my .php file and my database expect the file to be Float.

Comment: What are these parameters to be used for? If they will be HTTP request parameters, then they will be sent as strings in any case, and needs to be parsed into the required type at the other end -- PHP not being statically typed should allow you to transform numeric-strings into numbers easily.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your method signature in order to return an other object/type.
So change `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Float>`.

```
protected Map<String, Float> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map <String, Float>params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("tire", 1.0f);
    params.put("tire2", 2.0f);
    return params;
}
```

Comment: I tired that already. My Map get the error saying "'getParams()' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest' clashes with 'getParams()' in 'com.android.volley.Request'; attempting to use incompatible return type"

Comment: I assume you want to override [this method](http://griosf.github.io/android-volley/com/android/volley/Request.html#getParams--). In this case you can't return anything else than Map<String, String>. You have to pass the float as a string and convert to float on the .php side.

Comment: What happens, when you rename your method?

Comment: @Donat Rashin is completely right. If op gets this error its derived by `StringRequest`. So you'll need to Convert your Float into an String.

Comment: @MapReduce, yes Rashin is right. I didn't see his comment when I added mine.